# change keymapping for a language fcitx5

Tags: fcitx

i want to type in bamini(tamil language keymap) with has different keymapping from any tamil input method available in fcitx5. So is there any way i can add another keymapping in fcitx5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new table based input method

Basically you need to use libime_tabledict command and have a corresponding config file.

You can take a look at file .conf.in and .txt file.
https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx5-table-other